# how to link libstdc++ using llvm lld

Tags: c++, llvm, lld

I want to link `test.ll` and `libstdc++.a` in window OS.

I have simple test IR code like this.

```
@.str = internal constant [14 x i8] c"hello, world\0A\00"

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...)

define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** %argv) nounwind {
entry:
    %tmp1 = getelementptr [14 x i8], [14 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0
    %tmp2 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf( i8* %tmp1 ) nounwind
    ret i32 0
}
```

I successed compile `test.ll` to `test.obj` with `llc`.

Now I want to make `test.exe` file with `lld` not gcc, cl

I`ve try this command but dosen't work...

`lld -flavor link /entry:main /implib:libstdc++.a test.obj`

It return this.

```
test.obj: undefined symbol: printf
error: link failed
```

My LLVM version is 4.0.0, lld version is 4.0.0

I Shoud use GCC? Help me Please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` is not provided by `libstdc++`, you need to link to a C standard library like msvcrt.
`/entry:main` isn’t necessary since `main` will be called by the crt.
`/implib` is not the option you are looking for. It specifies the name of the import lib to *generate*.

Using `g++ test.obj` successfully links your `test.obj` (created with `clang-cl -c test.ll`) to the mingw-w64-crt and creates a runnable program.
`clang++ test.ll` (this is mingw-w64 clang in msys2) does effectively the same.
You can check the invocation with `-v` to find out which objects and libraries were linked.

You can also link to the [static microsoft crt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(v=vs.80).aspx) with: 
`clang-cl -fuse-ld=lld-link test.ll libcmt.lib`

Not using lld with clang-cl currently (LLVM 4.0) doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Using gcc would work, but lld has an option `-lc` which tells it to link to the c++ standard lib.  You might need to drop the `-flavour link` option and go with the unixy style interface though.

Comment: Don’t you mean C standard lib? Also, are you sure that `-lc` works windows, there is no libc that i’m aware of, only msvcrt.